# Android CameraX: Taking picture takes too long

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using CameraX to take a picture with `ImageCapture.takePicture()`.

Here is the implementation:

```
imageCapture.takePicture(
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
    object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
            // ...
            image.close()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)
        }
)
```

When I click on a button to invoke the above, it takes approximately 1.5 seconds to take the picture which includes converting the `ImageProxy` into a `Bitmap` and rotating it.

Even when I have an empty callback, it still takes 0.5 seconds to complete.

I have tried setting the capture mode to `ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY` and the JPEG quality to a value below 100, but there was no noticeable difference.

Also, when I click to take a picture, the `PreviewView` goes black during this period, which I am not sure is supposed to happen.

Any ideas here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500ms for taking a picture is expected, especially on a lower end device. Converting it to a Bitmap and rotate can be slow, however, 1s seems long. I wonder how you did it. PreviewView should not goes to black. That's an unexpected behavior. If you have a minimal reproduciable code sample, I can take a look.

Comment: @Xi张熹 I was working on the Github repo for you and strange enough, the capture process was almost instantaneous and there was no black screen, even though I was basically copy and pasting. It may have something to do with the way I was configuring the camera, I'll get back to you if I get the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to change the lens from front to back or the other way round, I was doing this:

```
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
    .requireLensFacing(cameraState.lensFacing)
    .build()

LaunchedEffect(cameraSelector) {
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
        {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                context as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, cameraState.imageCapture
            )
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraState.previewView.surfaceProvider)
        },
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
    )
}
```

Now, I am holding the value of `lensFacing` in a state object which is a class annotated with `@Stable`, which I don't know makes any difference in this context.

Anyways, when I pass `cameraSelector` and invoke `ImageCapture.takePicture()`, the `PreviewView` goes black and the process takes noticeably long as stated above.

Instead of passing in `cameraSelector` into the `LaunchedEffect`, I pass in `cameraState.lensFacing` instead, and the `PreviewView` does not go black anymore and the process is significantly faster.

There may be a better way, but so far, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want exactly what is displayed in the PreviewView to be saved instantly, another way (not using `ImageCapture.takePicture()`) is to just have a `bitmap` variable and then take the bitmap directly from the PreviewView when you invoke your own `takePicture()` method.

```
val image: Bitmap

fun takePicture() {
    image = previewView.bitmap
}
```

This wont work if you need flash or any of the post processing stuff. But it works if your only goal is to take instant pictures. I use this together with the `ImageCapture.takePicture` and if the flash mode is off, use the bitmap way. If the flash mode is on, use the `ImageCapture` way and it seems to be working for me.

Another downside of this is that without more logic, the dimensions of the output pictures will be whatever dimensions you have the previewView set to.